# Is it against the rules to import and use ES6 classes in Vue.js components?

Tags: vue.js, es6-class

I have been using ES6 classes in some vue.js components just to simplify the code, but some devs told me that importing and using ES6 classes in Vue.JS is wrong. So, what is your opinion about that?

Comment: Do those devs told sth like this: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuejs-and-es6-es2015-classes/5380/2 . This guy, Linus Borg, should be in Vue dev team and through the bottom he says: *We use an options object to define a Vue component instead of an ES6 class*. Still, if you evaluate the objections you've faced thoroughly, people can discuss it into a larger depth.

Comment: Well, I have not extended the Vue with my classes, I only used them for complex data manipulation, just to keep code in my component as cleanest as possible.